# Cross building in sbt with 2.10.0

Tags: scala, sbt

I am cross building a scala project with sbt 12.1.

```
crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.9.2", "2.10.0")
```

However, it can't find the dependencies because they are named `_2.10` not `_2.10.0`.  It seems like it's regular to name your library `2.10` instead of `2.10.0` with the exception of `scala-language` and `scala-compiler`.  For example, scalaz is not found at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaz/scalaz-core_2.10.0/6.0.4/scalaz-core_2.10.0-6.0.4.pom but at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaz/scalaz-core_2.10/6.0.4/scalaz-core_2.10-6.0.4.pom.

Is there an easy way to handle this without writing custom rules for all of my dependencies?

The actual build.sbt is available [online](https://github.com/knowitall/common-scala/blob/master/build.sbt).

Comment: I also noticed that some libraries are suffixed `2.10` and some `2.10.0`, and find that rather unfortunate. I might just not have noticed it back then, but I don't remember running into a similar problem with Scala 2.8 and 2.9.

Comment: So in other words--special case them all? ;-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `2.10.x` releases are binary compatible between each other, libraries need to be built only with one version of scala library - and they can (and must) drop the `.0` part (if you publish with sbt, it is done automatically). When the maintainer of a library releases a library with `_2.10.0` tag, it's a mistake and you should consider filing a bug.

By the way, I looked on your `build.sbt` - running `+compile` on it works for me (sbt 0.12.1). Do you experience some errors?

Comment: With an old version of sbt (it doesn't give version info with `-version`) I get an exception that many `2.10.0` libraries cannot be found.  But after upgrading to `sbt` `0.12.1` it correctly drops the binary compatible version number and looks for `2.10`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Scala version incorporated into the artifact name in the Scala way, you specify the dependency with the `%%` operator:

```
libraryDependencies += "io.backchat.jerkson" %% "jerkson" % "0.7.0"
```

When the exact match is not available, you can specify the Scala version explicitly (but remember compatibility only exists across patch releases of a given major/minor release of Scala):

```
libraryDependencies += "io.backchat.jerkson" % "jerkson_2.9.2" % "0.7.0"
```

Comment: Yes, I do this in the pom file specified.  The problem is that I cross validate with 2.10.0 but dependencies use 2.10 (without the trailing .0).